# Interface a microcontroller and a printer .. code it in C programming

Tags: c, printing, microcontroller

Guide me how to program in "C" to interface a microcontroller with a printer.??
Also explain me the procedure of how actually printing is related to a micro controller.??

Comment: Sounds like a lab project. What have you done so far?

Comment: Please ask on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @vivin: yes.. its my lab project.. But i've just started doin gwith it??

Comment: Like I mentioned, start with the data sheet. I'm sure your professor has at the very least gone over the basics of writing a device driver. This is all you should need :) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the data sheet for the microcontroller. It will tell you everything you need to know about the microcontroller. As far as writing the actual device driver, it depends on what OS you're on. If you're on Linux, you can look up subject-matter related to writing Linux Device-Drivers. Without providing any more context, and without telling us what you've tried so far, there is not much we can do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read datasheet on microcontroller. Get interface schematics.
2. Write your microcontroller port manipulation layer (Write/Read port etc.)
3. Read docs on Microcontroller-Printer interface.
4. Write lowlevel interface layer.
5. Read docs on printer control language
6. Write printer manipulation layer
7. Read docs on image/text storage format you want to printer.
8. Write format decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont close this question, it is perfectly valid, just needs more clarification.  As mentioned the programmers reference or data sheet for the microcontroller is useful.  the most important is the piece you left out, how is this printer connected?  On an 8 bit parallel port?  On a network interface for which the microcontroller is also on a network?  Or many other possibilities.  And the answer lies in the data sheets or protocol definitions for the interfaces a combination of microcontroller documents and printer documents as well as some hopefully open standards in the case of network protocols.